# Execute dynamic SQL read only to prevent insert/update/delete of SQL injection attack? (select/read attack is ok)

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have a stored procedure which creates dynamic SQL from user input and executes it.

```
create proc MySP @input nvarchar(max)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = // generate sql using @input and data from tables
-- The generated SQL will need to access linked server too
exec(@sql)
```

To prevent SQL injection attack of insert, delete, update, drop, etc. (select is ok), will `exec(@sql) as login='aReadonlyLogin'` work? Is it a way without using a read-only login? The developer may not have permission to create a new login.

Comment: this entire thing IS sql injection.. how do you expect to prevent it?

Comment: it's still SQL injection whether it's reading or not. It sounds like you want to prevent anything besides SELECT?

Comment: What ever problem you are trying to solve, you are going about it the wrong way. Just my humble opinion

Comment: Read (select) is ok, just need to prevent insert, update, drop, and delete, etc.

Comment: Guarding against sql injection likely has more to do with how you handle the `@input` variable than how you handle the linked server login.

Comment: Can you show an actual example of a "good" and a "bad" input value?

Comment: User input is a weapon. The easiest way to avoid SQL injection is to not accept user input and execute it blindly.

Comment: "User input is a weapon." I'm going to credit you every time, but I'm going to steal that, @AaronBertrand

Comment: If you're going to let a user type a whole query, pass it in, and execute it, you're just in for a world of hurt. You can do all the sanitizing and replacing and escaping you want, a determined person **will** get past it, I promise you. You can see some other questions and tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200256/how-can-i-avoid-sql-injection-attacks), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/).

Comment: @EricBrandt I can't claim that as original copyright, but I do forget where I picked up the concept.

Comment: Let users input *values*, but don't let a user input *code* (an SQL query counts as code).

Comment: A `select` can do damage too. It may not modify data, but it can generate load on your database server that will crash the server.